# Threejs Raycaster hits objects when slightly outside the object

Tags: typescript, vue.js, three.js

I have a threejs scene inside a vue component.  I need to be able to select objects using the mouse and am using the OnPointerDown event and raycaster to find objects under the mouse pointer. This almost works but it seems like the code for raycasting is locating each object slightly to the left and up of where it really is.  I think this may be something to do with width and height of the camera and so on but I can't work out what.  I'm actually creating a 2D scene by using an OrthographicCamera with no rotation

my app is like this:

```
<template style="height:100vh">
  <v-container fluid style="height: 100vh;" >
    <v-layout fill-height>
        <ViewPort />
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

`ViewPort` is my component which is too large to post here, so I'll just post the key bits:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import * as THREE from "three";
  import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

  @Component<ViewPort>({
  components: {},
  mounted() {
    this.init();
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    if (container) container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    this.animate();
  }
})
```

Initialisation

```
private init() {
  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
  this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf0f0f0);

  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  if (!container) return;
  const width = container.clientWidth;
  const height = container.clientHeight;
  this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -width / 2,
    width / 2,
    100,
    -height + 100
  );
  this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
  this.scene.add(this.camera);

  this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
  this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = false;

  document.addEventListener("pointerdown", this.onPointerDown, false);
  window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize, false);
}
```

Get intersected objects on pointer down:

```
private onPointerDown(event: any) {
  this.node = undefined;
  this.onDownPosition.x = event.clientX;
  this.onDownPosition.y = event.clientY;

  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  if (container){
    this.pointer.x = (event.clientX / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    this.pointer.y = -(event.clientY / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  }
  this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.pointer, this.camera);

  const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(
    this.scene.children,
    true
  );
  if (intersects.length > 0) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

I can't work out what I should be doing to set the size of the threejs camera etc.  So where it says "do stuff" i change the colour of the object to select it.  How should I be setting the camera size?  I want the above component to be usable anywhere and therefore the scene to set its size and so on appropriately.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer my own question:

```
if (container){
    this.pointer.x = (event.clientX / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    this.pointer.y = -(event.clientY / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  }
```

should be:

```
if (container){
    this.pointer.x = (event.offsetX/ container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    this.pointer.y = -(event.offsetY/ container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  }
```